# send xml file to handler using http-post

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, handler

```
    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            if (fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType == "text/xml")
            {
                Stream inputstream = fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;

                byte[] streamAsBytes = (ConvertStreamToByteArray(inputstream));

                string stringToSend = BitConverter.ToString(streamAsBytes);

                xmlstream.Value = stringToSend;

                sendXML.Visible = true;
                infoLabel.Text = string.Empty;
/*
                string path = Server.MapPath("GenericHandler.ashx");
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.UploadFile(path,"POST", fileUpload.PostedFile);
                 Something like this maybe? But is there any way to do it without saving the file?            */

            }
            else
            {
                infoLabel.Text = "Please select an XML file";
                sendXML.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my current code. The xml gets saved in a hidden field as a hex string and sent via jquery ajax. But it would be much better to send the file itself and process it in the handler. Is that possible?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "asp.net c#: ". That's what we have tags for on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, i haven't tested it but it should work, instead of string pass the byte[] to the method

```
    private string PostData(string url, byte[] postData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writeStream.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        }
        string result = string.Empty;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Found the code here at [Http Post in C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a `HttpWebRequest`, set it's `Method` to `POST` (if that's what you need) and then create a form field in the request with your file data.  You will need to understand a little bit about how HTTP requests work and how to properly create that form field in the request, but it's doable (and not overly difficult).